# error of changing a tablename in IBM netezza aginity workbench

Tags: sql, linux, windows-7, netezza

I am trying to change a table name in IBM netezza Aginity workbench on win7.

I can read the table but I cannot change its name.

When I run :

```
 ALTER table my_database.username.my_table rename to my_database.username.my_table_new
```

I got error:

```
 ALTER TABLE permission denied
```

When I did this as admin in Linux server where I run nzsql and entered into "system(admin)=> " and ran the same command, I got:

```
 ERROR:  Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must be connected to the database that contains the table you are trying to alter.

From the nzsql prompt, type "\c my_database" and the reurn the alter table command. In your case you were connected to the SYSTEM database, and not MY_DATABASE.